# What is the impact of changing the Publication Path/URL on a published site?

Tags: 2013

I have a site Publication which is already published to staging. Now I want to change the path/URL defined in the properties of the Publication from `\ab_xyz\` to `\st_uvw\`.

Before I do so, I would like to know what the impact of this change is to the existing, published site?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify why you believe this is more complicated than 'click on the text field and change the value'?

Comment: I just want to understand the impact as the site is already published.

Comment: I see. In that case, might I suggest that you edit your question to focus on what the impact is of changing the publication URL when a site is already published? It would make it a lot clearer what the actual question is, making it easier to answer. It will also help others who might have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The impact is mainly on any configuration you have that uses the old URLs and paths. When you publish the Publication after changing the URL or Path, the files will be moved and the URLs used in Component Links (for instance) will be updated.

If you have the old URLs or paths used somewhere (e.g. in configuration files or - perish the thought - in hard-coded links) you will need to update those manually.

Comment: I believe this includes "images" (multimedia) and the links to images as well, which could impact any direct URLs the business has been using (e.g. links to PDFs). Oh, and changes in capitalization _might_ have a small impact on any analytics that reports on links.

Comment: Yes Alvin,It includes all the properties related to the publication.